# Set background on SurfaceView

Tags: android, background, surfaceview, android-framelayout

I’m developing an Android drawing app, using a `SurfaceView` (to be more specific it’s a class that extends `SurfaceView`). I already saw a lot of topics on this forum, but I didn’t get my answer.
My activity is basically a `FrameLayout`, which contains all of my views. I would like to set my `SurfaceView` on the lowest level of my `FrameLayout`, in order to see the upper elements (buttons, fragments, etc.). I also would like to set the background of my `SurfaceView` with a drawable but I’m facing problems.
I tried first to set the background of my `SurfaceView` itself and it works. Unfortunately, my painting content (canvas and bitmap) was overload by this background so I tried a second solution. I apply the drawable background to my `FrameLayout`, and I set my `SurfaceView` background as transparent, using `setZOrderOnTop`. My `SurfaceView` was indeed transparent, but my drawing stuff was above my buttons and fragments.
So my first question is: why do we need to `setZOrderOnTop` to get a transparent background? Then, how can I set a simple drawable background, keeping my structure hierarchy?
Thank’s for your answers!

**XML View:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/repeat_background"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <!-- Option menu -->
    <fragment ... />
    <Button ... />
    <Button ... />
    <Button ... />

    ...

</FrameLayout>
```

**@drawable/repeat_background**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/drawing_font_texture"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

**MyActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle p_savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(p_savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_controller_activity);

    // Getting my FrameLayout
    FrameLayout mainFrame   = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainFrame);

    // Instantiating my SurfaceView
    this.drawableView       = new MCustomDrawableView(getApplicationContext());

    // Don't works
    //setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);

    this.drawableView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    this.drawableView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams style = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


    // Add the SurfaceView to the FrameLayout, on lowest position
    mainFrame.addView(this.drawableView, 0, style);
}
```

Comment: SurfaceView has two parts, the "Surface" and the "View".  The View part is just supposed to be a transparent area used for layout.  The Surface is a completely separate layer that will be above or below all of the View elements.  If that's not what you want, just use a custom View instead -- it'll mix better with other Views, and the Canvas rendering will probably be hardware-accelerated.  http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is on the right way. Set the background to the framelayout or add another layout under the surfaceview for your drawable. Then increase the z indices of the surfaceview AND the z indices of the buttons/elements that should be over the surfaceview,otherwise they are under it. 
If you use material design, you can also set the elevation in dp for nice shadows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I set the background to another View (e.g. my LayoutView), I have to make sure that my SurfaceView background is transparent (in order to see the View below). For that, I have to use setZOrderOnTop and this is a serious problem for me because it set the SurfaceView on the very first level. Even I try to manage the z order of the other elements, they are still below.

Comment: Have you tried to set the background of your surfaceview to transparent or null?

Comment: And when you draw on your surfaceview make sure that you draw on a transparent background

Comment: Indeed. Actually, the background of my SurfaceView IS transparent. this.drawableView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

Comment: Try to set in the xml the background of your surfaceview null and look what happened. Can U see your below background? And can you try to change the framelayout to a relativelayout or do you need a framelayout?

Comment: My SurfaceView is not created from in xml file but from my Activity. When I set the background to null, screen becomes black (I guess this is the default background for my SurfaceView?) and I cannot see the below view. Unfortunately, I have to use a FrameLayout, mainly for my fragments.

Comment: But wait. You develop a drawing app right? Why don't you use a canvas instead of the surfaceview? They are more powerful and easier to handle. Then you can use one canvas for your drawing stuff and one view/canvas for your background image.
What do you mean? Does it fit for you?

Comment: Actually I already use canvas and bitmap for my drawing stuff, according the double-buffering method. It allows me fluid and high performances and this part works pretty well. I also tried to draw a bitmap as background for my view, but it was less effective. Moreover, I need a repeat font texture (android:tileMode="repeat") and I didn’t find how to do it with a bitmap.

Comment: Ok but the problem is, that the SurfaceView is programmed to have no transparent background. When you use a font, you don't need a background image or a bitmap. You can draw it with a path like this:

`Paint paint = new Paint();`
`paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);`
`paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);`
`canvas.drawPaint(paint);`
`paint.setColor(android.R.color.black);`
`paint.setTextSize(20);`
`canvas.drawText("Some Text", 10, 25, paint);`

Comment: Thank you, it works! I just used `setShader` instead `setColor`, to get my drawable texture. You said that `SurfaceView` is not programmed to have transparent background, do you know why? Is there some similar object `View` which has this ability?

Comment: I had a smilar problem with SurfaceView and the camera and found something like that in several posts, but I didn't find it to reference. I want to show you something and fortunately it worked for you, great :) It was a pleasure to help you.